# IOS7 Navigation bar cancel button is look like in IOS6

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, uibarbuttonitem, ios7

I am using the MFMessageComposeViewController to present the email composer. It shows the navigation buttons with the IOS7 style (simplified - only text with blue color), which is fine.
But when I'm using imagePickerController in order to get an image from the photo album I get the IOS6 bar buttons
[image]

I thought that the IOS decide about the style

Comment: It does, this could be a bug.

Comment: How do I notify Apple?

Comment: At http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep this question open just in case